# Read FT2332H FIFO Data

Tags: fifo, ftdi

I tried to read the FIFO buffer in FT2332H and it was successful but the to data is coming is a format make it difficult to process or plot it .. Here is the example ... I use ftd2xx library

```
while True:
    rxn = d.getQueueStatus()
    if (rxn>1024):
        print(bytearray(d.read(1024)))
```

The output is as below .. Each 4 is a byte received from the buffer .. How to get each

```
bytearray(b'4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444')
```

This is the result without bytearray

```
print((d.read(1024)))

b'4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444'
```

Comment: Hey, so...what exactly is the problem now? The convesion from a single byte into bits? Btw, looks like python. Why did not you not tag it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is python:

You can index each individual byte in the byte array with []

`my_buffer = bytearray(d.read(1024)`

now `my_buffer[0]` holds the value of the first byte in your byte array, represented as an *integer with value 0-255*. You will need to additionally cast this integer to a character to create a character array / string. ASCII is the typical correlation between an integer value and its character representation. The order of the bytes in your FIFO buffer is dependent on what is putting bytes into the FIFO on the not-USB side of the FT232. Many devices send data most-significant first, but you should verify this against that device's data sheet.

Comment: Great, it worked .. Thanks a lot .. The new code is

    if (rxn>1024):
        print("rxn= ", rxn)
        my_buffer = bytearray(d.read(1024))
        print(chr(my_buffer[0]))